# How does this bridge rectifier work?

Tags: capacitor, diodes, full-bridge

I opened up a charger that charges a lithium battery. When I opened it up I noticed that the bridge rectifier looked like this:

[image]

[image]

I thought they would use your regular type of diode like this:

[image]

Can someone explain how that rectifier works and why it has three plates? Wouldn't this form a capacitor?

Edit 2:

[image]

What does this do?

[image]

Comment: The capacitance of the plates spaced cm from each other will be in the pF range, negligible at mains frequencies. Three plates probably because of three phases or it was a mechanically better alternative to the designer. Size-wise, the small diodes you show are capable of hundreds of mA and the big heatsinked ones probably hundreds of A.

Comment: Sure, the plates form a capacitor; how much capacitance would they give? How would this capacitance compare with the typical capacitance of the diodes themselves (look at some typical 10A+ rectifier datasheets to get some ideas here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a three phase rectifier: -

[image]

This came from one of your images.

See the squiggly lines like this ~ <-- they represent the connections to the 3-phase supply.

> *When I opened it up I noticed that the bridge rectifier looked like
> this*

It's a very powerful 3-phase rectifier capable of delivering probably a few tens of amps to maybe 100 amps. The tiny diodes in your bottom picture would burn at this level of current in a second.

The plates act as heat sinks. The diodes should be one of these from the [Huajing rectifier site](https://www.thyristor.com.cn/product.php?partid=3&mpid=3).

[image]

> *What does this do?*

That looks like a current shunt; make there is a system that monitors current or, maybe it's just a meter on a wall. Hard to say.

Comment: How do three metal plates form 6 diodes?

Comment: The plates are heat sinks, the diodes will be obscured by the plates @JoeyB

Comment: @JoeyB The diodes are mounted on the plates, the plates act as heasinks and busbars.

Comment: @Andyaka I added a new pic in Edit 2. So those white circular things are the actual diodes? I also added another question in Edit 2

Comment: You should try and get a better picture. The question about the thing --> it looks like a current shunt for monitoring current @JoeyB --> see if you can identify the diodes from the [Huajing rectifiers page](https://www.thyristor.com.cn/product.php?partid=3&mpid=3).

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I see how it works now!

Answer (score 3):

That appears to be a three phase rectifier with six stud type rectifiers bolted to a hefty heat sink. Probably rated 50 amps or so.

Some examples of stud mount rectifiers:
https://www.vishay.com/en/diodes/med-high-diodes/stud/

[image: Here is one rated about 50A]
[image: And a smaller one rated 16A]

These often come as reverse polarity devices to avoid having to insulate the mounting stud.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I see how this works now. I thought the three metal plates were the diodes. This makes a lot of sense now